# Not Support Yet DexException

Tags: dex2jar

I'm trying to run the d2j-dex2jar command on Santoku VM to convert .apk file to .jar file, but everytime it is giving me this exception :

[image]

I'm fairly new to using this tool. I found a website which told me to transfer the apk file into the extracted folder of dex2jar, and I've tried that too, even updated the system once, but nothing seems to work. Although the .apk gets extracted into .jar even with the error, but after that I'm not able to convert the .class files into java code, which makes me conclude that there is something wrong with the dex2jar due to this error/exception, as everything else is working fine. What causes this error and how to solve it?

Also, does any other open source alternatives to dex2jar tool exist? To convert .apk to .jar or .zip files?